# jQuery create and append multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created 2 divs, Div1(freeze) Div2(parent) and again 3 divs(loading, header, msg) appended it to Div2(parent). Entire divs in to body tag. Below are my code, I think there is some other best way to achieve this.

```
    var freeze = $('<div/>',{
        "class" : "freeze"
    });
    var parent = $('<div/>',{
        "class":"parent"
    });

    var loading = $('<div/>',{
        "class":"loadimg"
    }).appendTo(parent);

    var header = $('<div/>',{
        "class":"header"
    }).appendTo(parent);
    var msg = $('<div/>',{
        "class":"msg"
    }).appendTo(parent);

    $('body').append(freeze,parent);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using jQuery for most of this is complete overkill and just makes the code longer than necessary. Since everything you have is a constant, you can just create a single string of HTML and append that to the body.

If you want jQuery references to parts of it for later use, then just use .find() to find them later.

For example, you could just do this:

```
var html = '<div class="freeze"></div>' + 
           '<div class="parent">' + 
               '<div class="loadimg"></div>' +
               '<div class="header"></div>' +
               '<div class="msg"></div>' +
           '</div>';
$(document.body).append(html);
```

---

For later references, you can do something like this:

```
var header = $(document.body).find(".header");
```

Comment: Keep in mind not to use user input variables in your html string because it could be used for XSS attacks. To prevent this, use [aleha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48754590/7451109).

Comment: Just because it isn't mentioned in the question doesn't mean that someone who googles for this question might have the exact same use case. In my mind, when they adapt that example, they should know this. I didn't want to criticize you in any way. Just as an information to others.

Comment: @shaedrich - No XSS attack is possible with the code as shown here because everything is a constant as defined by the server, with no outside content injected in.  So, this solution to the OP's issue has zero vulnerability to XSS attacks just like aleha's answer which you referenced.  This solution was written because the OP asked for something simpler than the jQuery-based solution they were using.  If there was outside content, then it would obviously have to be dealt with carefully and similarly aleha's answer would also have to deal with it carefully.

Answer (score 42):

Since the question is about creating and appending multiple **objects** at the **same time** using jQuery, here is an approach:

```
$('body').append([
    $('<div/>',{ "class": "freeze" }),
    $('<div/>',{ "class": "parent" }).append([
        $('<div/>',{ "class": "loadimg" }),
        $('<div/>',{ "class": "header" }),
        $('<div/>',{ "class": "msg" })
    ]);
]);
```

In some cases operating with structural data is more reliable and more convenient than raw markup

Answer (score 3):

jQuery methods often implement the decorator pattern which means you can nest calls:

```
el = $('<div>').addClass('parent')
       .append(
         $('<div>').addClass('loadimg')
       );
```

In this example, you add a child `div` to some parent `div`. You may use more `.append` here and decorate them with `addClass`, `attr`, and many other jQuery methods.

The developer of jQuery already did the hard work implementing the decorator pattern, it is time to honor their efforts and start using it.

Comment: I don't understand how this is decorator pattern?

Comment: It's the [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Please use symbol backtick '`' in your front and end of html string, this is so called template literals, now you able to write pure html in multiple lines and assign to variable.

Example >>
var htmlString =

`

Your

HTML

`