# Why "message here" text seems like bold

Tags: jquery

I'm using `jQuery` to append `<div>`, and it's appending an extra close icon but I can't see why. If you run the code snippet below and click on `"Add more"` link, you'll see an additional times `(x)` icon, and the `"message here"` text seems bolded.

```js
$(function() {


  $("#add").click(function() {
    $('<div class="row domainName"><div class="col"><div class="input-group mb-2"><span class="input-group-text bg-white"><i class="fas fa-lock text-secondary"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domain"><span class="remove input-group-text bg-white"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fas fa-times"></li></a></span></div></div><div class="col"> message here </div></div>').appendTo("#DomainsList");
  });

  $("#DomainsList").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest('.domainName').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<section id="DomainsList">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <span class="input-group-text bg-white"><i class="fas fa-lock text-secondary"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domains">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">message here</div>
  </div>
</section>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little problem is interrupt your output. Your starting tag is `<i>` and closing tag is `<li>` while you append message block inside `#DomainsList` that is the problem.

**Look here for how to `create and append` multiple elements in jQuery, it's make your code easy to read**

[jQuery create and append multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498082/jquery-create-and-append-multiple-elements/48754590)

Change:

```
<i class="fas fa-times"></li>
```

To:

```
<i class="fas fa-times"></i>
```

Here down is modified code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var appendBlock = '<div class="row domainName">' +
                            '<div class="col">' +
                                '<div class="input-group mb-2">' +
                                    '<span class="input-group-text bg-white">' +
                                        '<i class="fas fa-lock text-secondary"></i>' +
                                    '</span>' +
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domain">' +
                                    '<span class="remove input-group-text bg-white">' +
                                        '<a href="javascript:void(0);">' +
                                            '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>' +
                                        '</a>' +
                                    '</span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="col"> message here </div>' +
                        '</div>';
                        
    $("#DomainsList").append(appendBlock); 
  });

  $("#DomainsList").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest('.domainName').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<section id="DomainsList">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <span class="input-group-text bg-white"><i class="fas fa-lock text-secondary"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domains">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">message here</div>
  </div>
</section>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked through my code so many times, and just missed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by typing error.

`<i>` tag should close with `</i>`.

In your code, `<i>` close with `</li>`.

Using template characters(`) instead of single quotes(') will help with readability when adding code as a string.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
    $(`
      <div class="row domainName">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <span class="input-group-text bg-white">
              <i class="fas fa-lock text-secondary"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domain"/>
              <span class="remove input-group-text bg-white">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </a>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col"> message here </div>
      </div>
    `).appendTo("#DomainsList");
  });

  $("#DomainsList").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest(".domainName").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<section id="DomainsList">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <span class="input-group-text bg-white"><i class="fas fa-lock text-secondary"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Domains">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">message here</div>
  </div>
</section>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add More</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good information to have!

Answer (score 1):

//do not use fas fa-times class from i tag and add into span tag html ,and add css .remove {    cursor: pointer;} for display hand cursor while mouse over on it, see bellow code  $("#add").click(function() {
$(' message here ').appendTo("#DomainsList");
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).